# Unable to Access Zend Server 5 CE after installation

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server-ce

I have previously installed WAMP on my windows, and now I am trying to install Zend Server 5 CE 5.3.1 Win x86.

During the installation of Zend Server, there is a step asking about:

- web server port : 80
- zend server interface port : 10081

I kept to the default. After the installation, I tried to access http://localhost,and is able to see zend test page. But I am unable to access http://localhost:10081/ZendServer, it was stated as `page not found`.

Is it a conflict of my WAMP and the Zend Server? I remembered stopping the apache for WAMP, before trying to access ZS. Could anyone please advise me how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution will probably be to cleanly uninstall both WAMP and Zend Server and afterwards just install Zend Server. On the other hand, it could be that another (unrelated) process is already using port 10081, so you might check that as well (using netstat for example) - checking the log files could help in finding this out as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem. It looked like another application was already using the port 10081.

1. To find out which application was using the port 10081 I used the following command (in a terminal). This will give you the PID (last column) of the application:

   netstat -ano |find /i "established"
2. Then, I used the Windows Task Manager (Ctrl+Alt+Del). Go to the "Processes" tab. Then View/Columns menu and tick PID. You should be able to locate the application with the PID.

Personally, it was my antivirus, McAfee, who was using that port.